# Matlab save ignoring large cell arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, save

I'm trying to save a cell array where each element is around 500mb when saved individually (which works without issues). The whole cell array has around 10 such elements.

When using the save command, the cell array is not saved at all, even when I explicitly try to save the cell array by variable name. No error messages occur. The resulting .mat files simply don't contain the variable (or nothing, in the case of an explicit save).

Sufficient disk space is available. Anyone got an idea what's going on?

Edit:
I'm using the save command the following way:

```
save(filename)
```

OR

```
save(filename, cellarrayname)
```

Comment: what version of matlab are you using? what version of `'mat'` format are you using? is it `v7.3` compliant?

Comment: I'm using 2013a. Where can I check the .mat file format?

Comment: How do you use the save command? Please put a small example in you questions.

Comment: look at preferences->general->MAT-files

Comment: Thanks, the default settings were v7 which caused the issue. I would like to accept this as an answer. However, it seems that this way of saving is much much slower than saving the individual parts. Is this normal behavior?

Comment: @JohnSmith: That's a known disadvantage, details are described [here](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/improving-save-performance).

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to resort to partial saving then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behavior of Matlab is to save in `v7` format, that is restricted by the file size. To overcome this, you should change the default behavior to `v7.3` that uses hdf5 file format and can handle larger files.

To change the default settings, go to *File* menu -> *Preferences* -> *General* -> *MAT-Files*:

[image]
<sub>(source: [undocumentedmatlab.com](http://images.undocumentedmatlab.com/Preferences_MAT.png))</sub>

As pointed by [David's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33199466/matlab-save-ignoring-large-cell-arrays?noredirect=1#comment54204133_33199466) more information can be found in [this link](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/improving-save-performance) regarding performance issues related to the `v7.3` file format settings.